# Empty Array AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have searched around a bit in hopes of finding a solution to my problem, but have had no luck. 
I am basically trying to pass data into the ajax function, but when it passes it to my php file it only returns an empty array (Yes there are a few topics on this, couldn't find any to fit my needs) , here is the console output: `Array ()`

Its odd because just before the ajax function I log the data, and it prints out each section with no problems.The posting URL is accurate, works fine straight from my form. I have tried to use response instead of data passed through the function, but no luck their either. 
Thanks in advance!

Here is the JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

    var that = $(this),
      url = that.attr('action'),
      type = that.attr('method'),
      data = [];

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
      var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

      data[name] = value;
    });
    console.log(data); /////THIS LINE HERE ACTUALLY PRINTS DATA
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

    return false;

  });
});
```

And here is my PHP

```
<?php //removed the issets and other checkers for ease of readability

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

UPDATE: I have tried to add method:"POST" to my ajax function and it still seems to be printing out blank arrays... Maybe I should convert everything to GET?

Comment: `method: "POST"` missing in ajax

Comment: Ahh. Tried this, and it is still printing out an empty array.

Comment: I have a theory, but it needs to be tested. At the top of your PHP file, when you put var_dump(file_get_contents(“php://input”)), what is the ouput then?

Comment: Here is the console log output: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
</pre>

Comment: I believe the problem is how you are submitting your data, I don't believe you can simply post an array, try changing your ajax from data: data, to data: {data:data}, if that doesn't work, maybe try not re-using the word data so much.

Comment: Ok, so I tried data:{data:data}, no luck. Gonna try to trim down the use of the word data and will post an update... Ok I changed the array name and still have the same result. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery** `ajax()` uses `GET` as default method. You need to mention `method: POST` for **POST** requests.

> method (default: 'GET')

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: "POST",
   type: type,
   data: data,
   success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Or you can also use `post()`.

Comment: So the keyword type is supposed to be my method. Just added method to my ajax function , along with post and it's still printing out an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

EUREKA!!! Wow, the mistake was much simpler than I thought, figured it out solo! Thank you everyone for the tips! Finally got it

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

var that = $(this),
  url = that.attr('action'),
  type = that.attr('method'),
  data = {}; // THIS NEEDS TO BE CHANGED TO BRACKETS!!
```